# Can't get my Discord bot to connect to voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm messing around with a bot for the first time but can't seem to get it to join a voice channel. I know the $join command is working because my bot will say "Connecting to {channel}" with the correct channel name, but it still never connects. If I'm not in a voice channel, the bot will correctly say "Error".

I've tried every single solution I can find online. Every time the bot will identify the correct channel but it simply won't join the channel. This feels like such a simple problem so I'm not sure how I can use similar code as others and still not have it work. Below is the code I'm using for the command. I left out all the prefix and bot setup code because all the messages I send work fine.

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx): 
  if (ctx.author.voice): 
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel 
    await ctx.send(f"Connecting to {channel}") 
    await channel.connect() 
  else: await ctx.send("Error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
asyncio.TimeoutError – Could not connect to the voice channel in time.
discord.ClientException – You are already connected to a voice channel.
discord.OpusNotLoaded – The opus library has not been loaded.
```

These are the following errors that the bot can raise for `VoiceChannel.connect()`

If you are not receiving errors when you should, this points towards a poorly made global command handler `on_command_error`.

You either want to remove that for the time being to get the actual error on the console, or fix it by output the error in a case where the error isn't handled. A common way of doing that is:

```py
import sys
import traceback

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
      if x: # let x, y, z be isinstance check for error
         # do this
      elif y:
         # do that
      elif z:
         # idk do something other than this and that
      else:
         print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
         traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)
```

After getting your actual error for joining the VC, check through these:

1. `asyncio.TimeoutError`: This error is raised when your bot has a
   weak internet connection or your ping is absurdly high, high enough
   to not make a connection.
2. `discord.ClientException`: Might want to check if bot is not in VC when it starts up, and also that you have relevant guild intents and voice intents enabled.
3. `discord.OpusNotLoaded`: Your device does not have `libopus` loaded, you might want to search for that online depending on what you use. If you are on an ubuntu-based linux distro, you can use `sudo apt install libopus0` and then try to see if it fixed your issue. I am not sure about windows

If you can't figure it out after you read the above stuff, let me know the **`EXACT ERROR`** you are facing, which includes the traceback message (the whole error text that will print onto your console)

Comment: I fixed an error with my error handler and found that I forgot to import nacl. Bot joins perfect now